# Mysqli undefine variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Hi I am working on simple crud project with php and mysqli statement.

First everything was working good, but for instance `mysqli_num_rows($result)` returns more than one row which cause all errors.

this is my PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["email"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["email"]))){
// Include config file
require_once 'db.php';

// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM interns WHERE email = ?";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

    // Set parameters
    $param_id = trim($_GET["email"]);

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
            contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            // Retrieve individual field value
            $firstname = $row["firstname"];
            $lastname = $row["lastname"];
            $cin = $row["cin"];
            $phone_number = $row["phone_number"];
            $address = $row["address"];
            $school = $row["school"];
            $intern_duration = $row["intern_duration"];
            $departement = $row["departement"];
            $cv = $row["cv"];
            $internship_report = $row["internship_report"];
        } else{
            // URL doesn't contain valid id parameter. Redirect to error page

        }

    } else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else{
// URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
header("location: error.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

I know it's might be a very simple error but it driving me crazy xD

Comment: *"undefine variable"* being which one? I can't count how many you have on a whim

Comment: its $row because mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 isn't valid it returns 2 rows but should return only 1

Comment: change `mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1` to `mysqli_num_rows($result) >0`

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id)` that should be an `s`.

Comment: I'm trying to get one row  Alive if I do what you say I always return the first row

Comment: then do `$sql = "SELECT * FROM interns WHERE email = ? LIMI 1";
`

Comment: Fred it worked thanks!! can I ask why ??

Comment: @MarouaneSihad welcome. I posted an answer with a probable cause for this. Until we know what's inside your db and values, then that'd be the best explanation I can offer at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id)` that should be an `s` for a string, being for the email address. The `i` stands for "integer".

Your query probably returns more than one row because there are (probably) more than one row containing an integer.

You could also add a `LIMIT 1` to the query which may help.

Comment: Yes, because I was working with 'id' first then change it to 'email'. Thank you

Comment: @MarouaneSihad ah! and you're most welcome. Enjoy the eclipse, safely ;-) *Cheers*